# Defining static routes other than default to similar route in home

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have set up a default route in my .NET MVC 5 app like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

So now whenever I access my site at:

```
localhost:59920
```

It opens me up the index controller from home.

Now I have more methods inside the same controller like:

```
Register, Login and such
```

How can I set up a route so that it looks like this:

```
localhost:59920/Login

localhost:59920/Register
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Attribute routing

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
  [Route("Login")]
  public ActionResult Login()
  {
     return View();
  }
}
```

With Traditional routing

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Login",
    url: "Login",
    defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Now when you request `yourSite/Login`, the Login action method in AccountController will handle that.